# Performing action over list of elements in Telerik Test Studio

Tags: katalon-studio, telerik-test-studio

I have a list of companies on the dashboard that I wish to test clicking on. When each company list item is clicked on, a checkmark should appear next to it. How to tell Test Studio to click on each one?

Company list looks like this :

[image]

and the HTML code is something like this (even though the point of me using Test Studio is to avoid coding) :

```
<ul id="companyList" class="list-group">

    <li class="list-group-item clickable " data--name="EzDine C2 - Michael" data--id="302">
        EzDine C2 - Michael
        <span class="list-check"><i class="fa fa-check text-success" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
    </li>

    <li class="list-group-item clickable " data--name="Test EZDine V2 Comp1" data--id="301">
        Test EZDine V2 Comp1
        <span class="list-check"><i class="fa fa-check text-success" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
    </li>

</ul>
```

I am familiar with Selenium WebDriver, Katalon, and the concept of stale elements (the state of elements when they leave the DOM).

Comment: I think I found what I'm looking for; /* they're called "data-driven find expressions" */

https://docs.telerik.com/teststudio/advanced-topics/coded-samples/general/data-driven-find-expressions